# Share Google Sheets Anonymously

Tags: google-sheets

I want to share a view only spreadsheet on my business web page, but the business gmail account we use isn't a public one, it's one we use internaly. We have other public emails with the business domain but they aren't Google ones.

So I would like to know if there's a way I can share the link on the web site, so that when customers anter the spreadsheet there's no way for them to access any information about the spreadsheet's owner, even if they save the spreadsheet to their drive.

Answer (score 1):

From [this post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/114961/share-google-sheets-anonymously),

> If you want to give the permission of viewer and editor to users for the shared spreadsheet, you are required to share the endpoint like `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/### fileId ###/edit?usp=sharing`. In this case, users can retrieve your information including name and email from file ID using GET `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/### fileId ###?key={YOUR_API_KEY}` of Drive API. Namely, it means that the method using the file ID gives the owner information to others. So how about this workaround?

> - When the spreadsheet is published to web, the URL is like `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/### Not fileId ###/pubhtml`. In this case, users cannot retrieve the file ID. So users cannot know the owner information.
>
>   - In thiscase, the shared URL is like `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/### Not fileId ###/pubhtml`.
> - Display the spreadsheet Using Web Apps. In this case, users cannot retrieve file ID, because the owner information cannot be retrieved from the Web Apps URL.
>
>   - In this case, the shared URL is like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/### Not fileId ###/exec`.
> - Display the spreadsheet using Google Visualization API and API key. In this case, users cannot retrieve file ID, because the owner information of the API key cannot be retrieved.
>
>   - In this case, In thiscase, the shared URL is the URL of your own site.

Credits to [Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/). Quote licensed under [CC-BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)